# Alter view data return?

Tags: 7, views, commerce

I am wondering if there is a way to do the following.

I need to alter view return data and either remove entries or keep entires based upon running some PHP.

Is there any easy way to do that? I was looking at the theme stuff, but that would mean I would nuke my pagination, is there anyway I could remove results but regenerate my pagination.

Sorry if this is confusing...

**Edit:** It's a little difficult to explain, but I am using Commerce. And I need to get a list of discounted products. But commerce only discounts products before they are displayed (ie there is no database I can join/where on to get discounted products). So I need to get all the products, then remove those that are not discounts.

Comment: If you're using a pager you'll need to do the alter at the query level ([`hook_views_query_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7)) otherwise things will go lopsided. If not, you can probably get away with [`hook_views_pre_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7), but it kind of depends exactly what you need to change and when

Comment: It's a little difficult to explain, but I am using Commerce. And I need to get a list of discounted products. But commerce only discounts products before they are displayed (ie there is no database I can join/where on to get discounted products). So I need to get all the products, then remove those that are not discounts.

Comment: Totally clear; that an interesting problem. I guess the discounts are applied by a rule?

Comment: Yes they are applied via Rules.

Comment: Looks like others are working on it: https://drupal.org/node/1020050. There are a couple of patches to try there, or perhaps get a starting point from

Comment: That seems like it might work. I'm a little worried about using a patch and a sandbox module. But I guess I'll just need to test more. Thanks @Clive

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_views_data` to alter view data like Commerce discounted products. As suggested by [*Clive*](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/108213/alter-view-data-return#comment128494_108213), here is the patch which is implementing related feature:

- [Allow Views to sort / filter based on pre-calculated prices](https://www.drupal.org/node/1020050)

Other hooks to consider which can allow to alter the views data are:

- [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7.x-3.x),
- [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7.x-3.x).